# Angular UI Router Wrong Template And Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an odd issue where I use an `ng-click` to `$state.go()` to a state, and get the correct url but the wrong template and controller.

These are my states:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/messages");
      $stateProvider.state('message', {
      url: "/messages/:to/:fro/:messageID",
      templateUrl: 'message.html',
      controller: 'MessageCtrl'
    }).state('compose', {
      url: "/messages/compose/a/message",
      templateUrl: 'compose.html',
      controller: 'ComposeCtrl'
    });
});
```

This is the function triggered by my `ng-click` and I am in fact getting the console log so I know the right one is firing.

```
$scope.composeMe = function(){
    console.log("You want to compose a message!");
    $state.go("compose");
    };
```

When I fire that function I get the url to change to `http://example.com/messages/compose/a/message` but I get the `templateUrl` and the `controller` of the `message` state.

Why is that? The other state is fired from a similar (`ng-click` derived) function and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are trying to go to matches the one you are actually going to.

How would ui-router know that "compose" isn't the to: field you want, "a" isn't the fro: field you want, and "message" isn't the messageID you want?

Move the more specific state definition above the one with URL parameters.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I thought it worked by matching states not urls but I can see now why that was wrong.